# Creating new layout DXL column in batch + picture export

Tags: ibm-doors

I have a DXL script that is intended to run in batch. In this script, we read in an XML file and create new columns for the referenced module based on the XML contents. Sometimes, we need to create layout DXL for a particular column that creates a bitmap that was drawn on a canvas and then call `exportPicture()` on that to create a local PNG.

The issue I'm facing is that when this `exportPicture()` method is run in batch, it just creates a blank 1KB image but if the same method is called when running through the GUI, it works just fine.

I can't provide too many details about the code but here's what I can share.

Creating the columns:

```
   insert(column columnIndex)
   dxl(column columnIndex, dxlScript)
   setColumnTitle(columnIndex, columnTitle)
```

Exporting the image:

```
if (hasDXLCanvas(thisColumn)) 
{
  exportPicture                                                   //-
    (                                                             //-
      thisColumn,                                                 //-
      thisObject,                                                 //-
      tempStringOf( longPictName ),                               //-
      formatPNG_                                                  //-
    )
}
```

Here's the DXL Layout Script

```
int       height = 0
int       width  = 0
string  pictName
DBE   canvas
Bitmap bitmap
pictName = getPictName( obj )

if( !null( pictName )  ) 
{  
    canvas = getCanvas()

    if( !null( canvas ) )
    {
       bitmap = loadBitmap( canvas, pictName, true, width, height )

        if( !null( bitmap ) )
        {
            drawBitmap( canvas, bitmap, 0, 0 )
        }

        destroyBitmap( canvas, bitmap )
   }
}
```

I'm assuming the issue has to do with drawing on a canvas in batch mode but I could be wrong. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In batch mode, lots of GUI functions are not available. There are some workarounds for some things, (e.g. loading a view is not allowed but you can modify the properties of the views so that the view to modify is the default view, then save and re-open the module), but don't expect everything to work.
Instead of using batch mode, you might want to experiment with the interactive mode and the command line switch -dxl (-D)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm even running into the same issue when running in interactive mode. I create the new layout dxl column with the dxl script that contains getCanvas(), loads the bitmap and then re-draws it. Then when I call exportPicture for that object and column, I get a blank image - is there a method to trigger the layout dxl to run prior to export? From the print statements I added into the layout dxl test script, it seems like it's only drawing it during the exportPicture call

Comment: well, there is a perm Declaration: "void refresh(Module m)" Operation: "Refreshes the display for open module m. Rational DOORS refreshes the current module after the termination of a DXL script. However, scripts that change the displays of other modules, or that create dialog boxes, need to manage display updates explicitly with this function. " Not sure if it helps here.

Comment: Yeah I've used that perm in the past to no luck. Based on what you said and what I've seen in my experience, using any DBE elements in batch mode doesn't work :/